# How to automate operations on similar tables

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I create a df based on another df (file.csv)

```
zuzycia.A6 <- file.csv %>% 
  select(
    Czas,
    `[A6] Energia [J]`,
    `[A6] Temp. zasilania [°C]`,
    `[A6] Temp. powrotu [°C]`,
    `[A6] Ilość wody [m3]`,
    
    `[B6] Temp. zasilania [°C]`,
  ) %>% mutate (
    `[A6] Temp. zasilania [°C]` = na.approx(`[A6] Temp. zasilania [°C]`, maxgap = 6, na.rm = FALSE), 
    `[A6] Temp. powrotu [°C]` = na.approx(`[A6] Temp. powrotu [°C]`, maxgap = 6, na.rm = FALSE), 
    Zuzycie.A6 = c (0, diff(`[A6] Energia [J]`)/10^9),
    narast = cumsum(coalesce(Zuzycie.A6, 0)) + Zuzycie.A6*0
  

ggplot(zuzycia.A6) + 
  geom_line (aes (x = Czas, y = `[A6] Temp. zasilania [°C]`), color = "red3", size = 0.3)+
  geom_line (aes (x = Czas, y = `[A6] Temp. powrotu [°C]`), color = "blue3", size = 0.3) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min.T.pow, max.T.zas)) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = format ("%H:%M"))
```

I have to repeat these operations many times. The following dfs will be created on their basis:
wear.A6, wear.B6, wear.K2 and many others.
I would like to automate these activities. You probably need to use loops (at the start I don't know how many groups are contained in file.csv: A5, B5, A6, B6, K1, K2 ..... )
I will appreciate any help

Comment: Whenever I have a group of similar/same tables on which I'll do the same steps, I refer to [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227), with many good techniques for doing so.

Comment: GrBa it would be helpful if you could include some of your input data, with dput, or some sample data, otherwise we're reduced to looking at your code (which doesn't say much), guessing at the data (when we will surely guess wrong), or providing (very) general advice (like r2evans has done above)